# Covariance of two random variables distributed uniformly over a rectangle

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I am looking at problem 36 on page 76 of Leo Breiman's text entitled "Probability and Stochastic Processes, With a View Toward Applications, second edition," wherein the goal is to calculate the covariance of two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, both of which are uniformly distributed over a rectangle.  The vertices of the rectangle are located at $(c,d)$, $(c,-d)$, $(-c,-d)$, and $(-c,d)$ where the long edges of the rectangle are parallel to the x-axes and $0\lt d \lt c$.  Leo Breiman states the answer as:
$$\Gamma_{X,Y} = \frac{1}{6}\left({c^2}-{d^2}\right).$$
In my attempt, I began by identifying the random variable $Y$ with the y-axes portion of the rectangle and the random variable $X$ with the x-axes portion of the rectangle.  I then guessed at the form of the probability density function, I tried:
$${x^2}-{y^2}, \text{(this form does not satisfy the conditions of a PDF)},$$
$${x^2}+{y^2},\text{and}$$
$${x^2}{y^2}.$$
Nothing worked.  Has anyone out there worked this problem to completion and, if so, would you mind letting me know what the correct form of the PDF is to use.  Thanks.

Comment: The rectangle has area $4cd$ so the pdf of $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed over the rectangle is something like $\dfrac{1}{4cd} I_{-c\le x \le c}^{\,} I_{-d \le y \le d}^{\,}$ where $I_{\cdots}^{\,}$ is an indicator function

Comment: @Henry as you have observed the cdf of $(X,Y)$ is of the form $f(x)g(y)$. This means $X$ and $Y$ are independent, doesn't it? I think the covariance is 0.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, though I slightly hesitate as the question may be saying $X$ and $Y$ are both uniformly distributed over a rectangle, i.e. each is a two-dimensional random variable and perhaps $(X,Y)$ is four dimensional

Comment: @Henry if the hypothesis just says X and Y have  a given distribution you cannot find the covariance. They may be equal ,independent, etc.

Comment: I must be missing something...  sorry...  $X$ is a 2x1 vector and so is $Y$.  What does it mean for their covariance to be a number?  Shouldn't the covariance be a 2x2 matrix?  (And if they are independently chosen, the covariance matrix would be diagnoal to reflect that.)

Comment: @user54738: For continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ covariance is given by: $\Gamma = \int\limits_{D}{\left(x-m_x\right)\left(y-m_y\right)}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$ where $D$ is taken to be the domain of the probability density function $f\left(x,y\right)$ and $m_x, m_y$ are the means of $X$ and $Y$. The probability density function must be defined so that $f\left(x,y\right){\ge}0$ for all $\left(x,y\right){\in}D$ and $1=\int\limits_{D}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$. Obvously, this is two dimensional, $X$ corresponds to $x$ and $Y$ corresponds to $y$ for any point $\left(x,y\right){\in}D$.